# Floating numbers for currency python

Tags: python, decimal

Currently I have written a program in *python* that calculates currencies and many other things. Now I noticed the `IEEE-754` problem on floating point numbers.

Is there a way to do correct mathematical operations like addition in python with the correct value?

As example:

```
0.1 + 0.1 + 0.1 = 0.3
```

I already tried  the `decimal` library but it seems that, it is not giving me correct rounded digits in rounded places.

Greetings.

Comment: Show what you're doing exactly, hard to say what are you doing wrong when you don't show that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using the `decimal` module, you need to initialize with strings; initializing with `float`s will preserve in high resolution the imprecision of the underlying `float` type. For example, using `Decimal(0.1)` actually produces a value:

```
Decimal('0.1000000000000000055511151231257827021181583404541015625')
```

because that's the 30 digit extrapolation of the value represented by the `float` `0.1`.

So instead of testing `Decimal(0.1) + Decimal(0.1) + Decimal(0.1) == Decimal(0.3)` (where you compute in fixed decimal precision, but initialize with non-decimal values), use `Decimal("0.1") + Decimal("0.1") + Decimal("0.1") == Decimal("0.3")` and you'll get the expected results.

Aside from that, you'll want to adjust the `decimal` context's `.prec` attribute to ensure you're preserving the intended amount of precision, but usually it's okay to preserve the full precision and just round to the correct precision later with the `quantize` method.

Comment: I think this will be the curret method. So if i use 0.1 as string then it should work !? Testing this now. Thank you

Comment: @ChristianNill: Yup. Strings can represent the number precisely for `Decimal` to parse; `float` introduces imprecision before `Decimal` gets a chance to look at the value; by the time `Decimal` sees it, it's too late.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try setting the context? For instance, the code below returns 0.3 as expected:

```
import decimal

decimal.getcontext().prec = 1
a = decimal.Decimal(0.1)
print(a + a + a)
```

Comment: Hi. Yes the context for precision is set.